# How can delete a draft for a no-reply sender?

Tags: sms

I have a few messages in my Messages app from contacts that don't support replies. I've accidentally forwarded a message from one of my other contacts to a non-reply contact, now whenever I look at the main Messages screen, I can see there's a draft under the no-reply contact, however when I enter that contact there's no draft at the bottom, nor any option to see the draft and/or delete it.

Is there any way to get rid of this phantom draft?

Comment: Trying to reproduce the issue, but I'm not having any luck forwarding to a non reply number. How did you do it? What sms app are you using? And what phone do you have?

Comment: Using OnePlus 3T on Android 8, using the latest version of Google's Messages app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with the app, I've found that this is something that Google messenger has overlooked. They don't have any option of clearing drafts.

After some research I [found](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/50963/241679) that it's safe to clear data of your messenger app. This will clear all drafts and unsent messages, but nothing else.
To do that, go to settings -> apps -> messages -> storage -> clear data.

Sent and received messages are not stored in the messaging app, rather they are stored in */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.telephony.*
(You might need a rooted phone to access this)
Therefore clearing the app data is not going to delete your messages.

I have tried this myself before recommending such a drastic move. (I did make a backup before that, just in case.)

Comment: Thanks. I have researched a lot of times until I found this useful solution.